# adding events to elements via for loop is causing all elements to only effect the last element in the loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, events

Edit: I have found an alternate solution to this. 
I can't answer my question yet because it is too new, and my rep is too low. But, 
Here is what I did:

```js
addIdToElements();
$(window).click(function(e){
  console.log('clicked'+ e.target.parentNode.id.replace("slider-arrow-right","")
})
```

```css
.content {
  position: relative;
}

.arrow-container {
  position: relative;
  top: -38px;
  width: 110%;
}

.slider-arrow {
  position: absolute;
}

.slider-arrow-right {
  right: 0px;
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.inner {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content" style="width: 400px; height:25px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
  <div class="outer" style="margin: 0 20px; overflow-x: auto; width:100%; height: 100%">
    <div class="inner" style="float: left; margin: 0px; width:25%; height: 100%; background-color: blue;">
    </div>
    <div class="inner" style="float: left; margin: 0px;  width:25%; height: 100%; background-color: orange;">
    </div>
    <div class="inner" style="float: left; margin: 0px;  width:25%; height: 100%; background-color: green;">
    </div>
    <div class="inner" style="float: left; margin: 0px;  width:25%; height: 100%; background-color: purple;">
    </div>
    <div class="inner" style="float: left; margin: 0px;  width:25%; height: 100%; background-color: yellow;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow-container">
    <div class="slider-arrow slider-arrow-left">
      <p class="stretch">&lt;</p>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-arrow slider-arrow-right">
      <p class="stretch">&gt;</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content" style="width: 400px; height:25px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
  <div class="outer" style="margin: 0 20px; overflow-x: auto; width:100%; height: 100%">
    <div class="inner" style="float: left; margin: 0px; width:25%; height: 100%; background-color: blue;">
    </div>
    <div class="inner" style="float: left; margin: 0px;  width:25%; height: 100%; background-color: orange;">
    </div>
    <div class="inner" style="float: left; margin: 0px;  width:25%; height: 100%; background-color: green;">
    </div>
    <div class="inner" style="float: left; margin: 0px;  width:25%; height: 100%; background-color: purple;">
    </div>
    <div class="inner" style="float: left; margin: 0px;  width:25%; height: 100%; background-color: yellow;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow-container">
    <div class="slider-arrow slider-arrow-left">
      <p class="stretch">&lt;</p>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-arrow slider-arrow-right">
      <p class="stretch">&gt;</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to make clickable arrows on my divs that will scroll the div horizontally by the clientWidth. When I click the first divs arrow however, it affects the second div. As you can see in the code below, clicked2 is displayed to console instead of click1 when I click the right arrow of the first div. Could someone please help point me in the right direction?

edit: removed irrelevant code.

```js
function addIdToElements() {
  var outerElements = document.getElementsByClassName("outer");
  var rightArrowElements = document.getElementsByClassName("slider-arrow-right");
  var leftArrowElements = document.getElementsByClassName("slider-arrow-left");
  for (var i = 0; i < outerElements.length; i++) {
    outerElements[i].id = "outer-" + i.toString();
    rightArrowElements[i].id = "slider-arrow-right-" + i.toString();
    leftArrowElements[i].id = "slider-arrow-left-" + i.toString();
  }
}

addIdToElements();
var outerClassElements = document.getElementsByClassName('outer');
for (var i = 0; i < outerClassElements.length; i++) {
  var currentOutterSection = document.getElementById('outer-' + i.toString());
  var currentRightArrow = document.getElementById('slider-arrow-right-' + i.toString());
  var currentLeftArrow = document.getElementById('slider-arrow-left-' + i.toString());
  currentRightArrow.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('clicked' + i);
  })
}
```

```css
.content {
  position: relative;
}

.arrow-container {
  position: relative;
  top: -38px;
  width: 110%;
}

.slider-arrow {
  position: absolute;
}

.slider-arrow-right {
  right: 0px;
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.inner {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content" style="width: 400px; height:25px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
  <div class="outer" style="margin: 0 20px; overflow-x: auto; width:100%; height: 100%">
    <div class="inner" style="float: left; margin: 0px; width:25%; height: 100%; background-color: blue;">
    </div>
    <div class="inner" style="float: left; margin: 0px;  width:25%; height: 100%; background-color: orange;">
    </div>
    <div class="inner" style="float: left; margin: 0px;  width:25%; height: 100%; background-color: green;">
    </div>
    <div class="inner" style="float: left; margin: 0px;  width:25%; height: 100%; background-color: purple;">
    </div>
    <div class="inner" style="float: left; margin: 0px;  width:25%; height: 100%; background-color: yellow;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow-container">
    <div class="slider-arrow slider-arrow-left">
      <p class="stretch">&lt;</p>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-arrow slider-arrow-right">
      <p class="stretch">&gt;</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content" style="width: 400px; height:25px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
  <div class="outer" style="margin: 0 20px; overflow-x: auto; width:100%; height: 100%">
    <div class="inner" style="float: left; margin: 0px; width:25%; height: 100%; background-color: blue;">
    </div>
    <div class="inner" style="float: left; margin: 0px;  width:25%; height: 100%; background-color: orange;">
    </div>
    <div class="inner" style="float: left; margin: 0px;  width:25%; height: 100%; background-color: green;">
    </div>
    <div class="inner" style="float: left; margin: 0px;  width:25%; height: 100%; background-color: purple;">
    </div>
    <div class="inner" style="float: left; margin: 0px;  width:25%; height: 100%; background-color: yellow;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow-container">
    <div class="slider-arrow slider-arrow-left">
      <p class="stretch">&lt;</p>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-arrow slider-arrow-right">
      <p class="stretch">&gt;</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Edit: I found an alternative way to do this that seems to work better: I have added a click event listener to the whole window, and then back track to find which arrow was clicked, and adjust accordingly. I will update the code in 2 days when I am able to answer the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a variable inside a "for" loop and an event inside that loop, you will ever point onto the last value of this variable when the event fires. Instead, set up an external function to which you pass your current variables values as arguments (they will have a new scope) and create your event from there.

For exemple:

```
for (var i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
  setAction(elements[i], i, elements);
}

function setAction(element, i, elements) {
  // console.log(element, i, elements);
  // element.addEventListener...
}
```

Or use the equivalent "forEach" loop that avoids this kind of issue:

```
elements.forEach(function(element, i, elements) {
  // console.log(element, i, elements);
  // element.addEventListener...
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/forEach

Comment: Thank you @Neii ! one quick note, I don't think forEach works on htmlcollections in some browsers, but the first solution seems like it would work.